# Cannot get Ubuntu 22.04 to complete boot

Tags: boot, usb

I am a total newbie so I really need step by step directions. I am on a Dell xps 13 and this is what I have on my screen:

```
[ 0.459335 pc1 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PI0 log size 0 is invalid
[ 0.471579] pc1 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PI0 log size 0 is invalid
/dev/nvme0n1p2 : clean, 428341/31227904 files, 118762740/124895488 blocks
```

What do I type? Can I move forward? I wouldn't mind just wiping it and starting over if I have to. I installed Insync for One Drive and it downloaded everything and now my disc is full and Firefox started crashing.. I restarted and now I have this. Please, please help me fix this. I have a USB drive of Ubuntu 22.04 but when I plug it in I get another error. It doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Two different and unrelated questions/problems  - can't boot Desktop Environment due to partition full and can't boot live/installation media -, the latter can indeed be the solution to the former. You may need to burn the USB stick again and/or check the boot order. Once in  the live session you can access the your files right away (unless encrypted) and delete the excess. Reboot and it should boot normally.

Comment: If you've used all your disk space, your installed system should still boot correctly & run, you will just be prevented from using a GUI (*a GUI requires enough space in $HOME or your user directory to create workfiles, if insufficient space is available the login fails & logout occurs without message; ie. login loop*).  If you're suffering from a *login loop* you don't need to re-install, but can login via text terminal & delete some files you don't need so as to create additional space allowing a GUI login to work.  This maybe your issue but it's unclear as you seem to talk about two issues

Comment: Thank you, both of you. But I can't get past the black screen with the above text. I have tried pressing enter, escape, y, n, my password... How do I get out of that screen? It just sits there with the blinking dash.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I tried bringing up the terminal with both the F2 and F3 options but it doesn't work. I am still stuck on the black screen with the response above.

Comment: "I have a USB drive of Ubuntu 22.04 but when I plug it in I get another error. It doesn't recognize it." What kind of an error do you have when you plug it in? Can you share the error? Also, can you try another USB drive with Ubuntu 20.04? Try to boot with it and try to get a live session to delete some unneeded files.

Comment: Sorry, not an error, it is this:  0.459335 pc1 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PI0 log size 0 is invalid
[ 0.471579] pc1 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PI0 log size 0 is invalid.  The other error just says "error 71". I did do another usb drive with 20.04 as you mentioned and that one doesn't work either...even tried a windows 10. Is there some way to get to the terminal from Grub 2.06?

Answer (score 0):

Dell XPS 13 9310 -

1. From Paul Menzel:
   (In reply to Paul Menzel from comment #28)

> @linparda, your problem is very likely unrelated. (In the GRUB menu, press
> the key e and remove `quiet` from the Linux kernel command line. Then boot
> with F10 or Ctrl + x.) It’s a problem you should report to Ubuntu though.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209943#c28

2. I switched out the Dell A to C usb adapter and was finally able to see the flash drive to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04.

Thank you everyone! Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try to get the terminal by clicking Ctrl+Alt+F2 or Ctrl+Alt+F3. If you are able to get a terminal, log in and open a bit place by cleaning unneeded files in your home directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean your home directory"?

Comment: I'm a noob and just struggled with getting the boot right,  Is the Ubuntu stick a download of the "try and/or install" from the Ubuntu site? Did you use it to install?

Comment: I'm a noob and I just struggled with getting the boot right,  Is the Ubuntu stick a download of the "try and/or install" from the Ubuntu site? Did you use it to install?  I had to change some info on the master boot info by using, I think, f10, to interrupt the boot process and change some info.  You might look on the Ubuntu noob forum for 'msh8r' about 5/25/22.

Comment: Boot problem with 22.04

  [1]: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2475097